Why are my stripe colors mapping incorrectly to my specified groups in ComplexUpset R package?
I'm creating an upset plot using the ComplexUpset package in R, and am trying to color the stripes of my sets based on a specified attribute from another dataframe. I'm using an approach almost identical to this example , but for whatever reason, two of the groups are incorrectly colored. I have absolutely no idea how this happened, and thus no idea on how to fix it.
Basically, any set ending in C should be colored salmon, any set ending in M should be colored blue, and the set ending in S should be green. However, the "TvC" set is blue when it should be salmon, and the "SvM" set is salmon when it should be blue.
library(ComplexUpset)

combined2 <- data.frame(letter = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                        SvC = c(1,0,1,0,0),
                        TvC = c(1,1,1,1,0),
                        MvC = c(1,0,0,0,0),
                        SvM = c(0,0,1,0,0),
                        TvM = c(0,1,1,0,0),
                        TvS = c(1,0,1,0,1)
                        )

combined_metadata <- data.frame(set = c("SvC", "TvC", "MvC", "SvM", "TvM", "TvS"), #set name
                                relative_to = c("C", "C", "C", "M", "M", "S")) #set attribute

upset(combined2,
      intersect = treats,
      mode = 'inclusive_intersection',
      intersections = list(
        "SvC",
        "TvC",
        "MvC",
        "SvM",
        "TvM",
        "TvS",
        c("SvC", "TvC"),
        c("SvC", "TvC", "MvC"),
        c("SvM", "TvM")),
      stripes = upset_stripes(data = combined_metadata, 
                              aes(color = combined_metadata$relative_to),
                              colors = c("C" = "lightsalmon",
                                         "M" = "lightskyblue2",
                                         "S" = "palegreen3")
                              )
      )

Here is the result of my code: enter image description here

Update for anyone curious:
I gave up on trying to figure out why this problem was happening and just manually set the color for each stripe.
